# ML techniques for subscription data

Tags: machine-learning, data-analysis, marketing

What are the ML methods one should use for subscription data comprising of visits, monthly active user, user interaction, product usage, location, source. predicting cost for our services.

Comment: ML methods to achieve what exactly?

Comment: like we want to get to know better which features are critical for increasing the product subscription conversion rate.

Comment: Then regression is what you need, IMO